# Mirroring a git subdirectory in a SVN subdirectory

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Yes, I know there are already a ton of version control questions on here, but none of the proposed solutions do exactly what I want them to do and I can't find a way to hack one together. I've been looking for a week now.

### My setup:

Windows 7 machine (with cygwin-- though I haven't touched it for this problem), remote password-protected git repo and svn repo. Gradually switching from using svn to git for new projects (no one has used git before) and need to shuffle code back and forth.

### What I want:

I and several other people should be able to work in `gitproject/path/to/sharedcode` and have our commits automatically update `svnproject/trunk/path/to/sharedcode`. This should only affect those two subdirectories, the rest of the repos should remain independent. **I'm looking for a one-way, permanent link from git to Subversion.** History needs to be preserved in git, but not in svn, as no development will take place there. Additionally, we would like this to be repeatable so in the future we can set up `anothersvnproject/trunk/path/to/sharedcode` as a mirror in the same way.

### Possible solutions:

- A script that checks for changes in `gitproject/path/to/sharedcode` (runs a `git diff`) and, if it finds any, copies them and pushes them to the svn repo. This could run automatically every day or be called by a dev who made some changes.
- A script like ^this^ that we could run when making commits instead of running `git push gitproject master` that pushes the changes to both git and svn.

or, if all else fails,

- A very clear, obvious workflow that all of us can follow easily when working in git. Something like "first, checkout gitproject with COMMAND. Then create a new branch named NAME with COMMAND. Then make your changes. Then go to LOCATION and run COMMAND..."

### What I've tried:

- [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) looks like overkill for our purposes, and I don't want to/don't have the authority to set it up since it's not open-source. I would like to do this without creating a new repo, as well.
- Using [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) to create a new repo in `gitproject/path/to/sharedcode` with `git svn init --trunk=http://svnhost.com/svnproject/trunk/path/to/sharedcode --no-minimize-url`. This creates a new local repo that I can push from, may be useful with a batch script, but it's not the ideal solution.
- [Git2Svn](http://repo.or.cz/w/git2svn.git) looks promising, but I can't find any documentation for it, so I don't trust it.
- I've used [Svn2Git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) (the one written in Ruby) before and it worked beautifully, but I don't think it has the functionality I need now.
- [Git-Subversion Bridge](https://github.com/mrts/git-svn-bridge) looks very similar to what we want with the automatic synchronization, but again, it's complicated and involves setting up a whole new repo. If I get help from the rest of the team we'll probably end up using this.
- I also tried writing the Windows batch script I described. It went something like: `git pull` the latest version of gitproject, run a `git diff` on `gitproject/sharedcode` and `svnproject/sharedcode`, pipe output to a txt file, use the awful, awful Windows `IF` statement to say that if `diff` picked up anything besides the README, `ROBOCOPY /MIR` the contents of `gitproject/sharedcode` to `svnproject/sharedcode`, `ROBOCOPY` the correct README from a backup to `svnproject/sharedcode`, `svn add` everything, `svn checkout` from the remote repo, and finally `svn commit`. It didn't work.

I'm sure I have all the pieces of a solution, but I lack the knowledge and coding skills to bring them all together. I'm hoping stackoverflow can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't operate on part of tree inside Git repo (in short words - it's monolithic object, contrary to SVN)
2. Due to p.1, you **must** split your Git repository and convert `/path/to/sharedcode` into additional special repository. You can use [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or [Subtree](http://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/) approach (trendy Git-boys prefer *today* Subtree)
3. With a dedicated repo you, using [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion), can add new remote to `svnproject/trunk/path/to/sharedcode` (Git-history will be mirrored to SVN, but it's the laziest and easiest way)

Comment: So no matter what specific solution I use, I will have to split the git repository or create a new one. That's important. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with [Lazy Badger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459166/309334). Though you can't check out part of a `git` repo. You can check out the `git` repo and use filesystem operations on the subtree. So, you can have two checkouts: one of the `svn` repo and the other of the `git` repo. Then you can use a script (maybe using `rsync`) to synchronize the appropriate subdirectories. There is no reason to check for differences. The version control will do this for you. Then you can commit the changes to the svn repo. This script can run as a `cron` job. This works as long as you only need to synchronize a single branch.

I cannot locate the code at the moment, but we have a large `git` repo and another team's `svn` repo maintains a read-only copy of a subtree using a similar method.